# how to go up the previous command written in Redis-Cli?

Tags: database, caching, redis, nosql

how to go back, on the previous command that i have written for redis cli 
e.g.. UP KEY for Cmd and Bath, or MySQL Cli or pretty match every other CLI, 
The Arrow up key does not seem to work in Redis Cli??
and thanks

Comment: Up key works well for me

Comment: Works for me too. What OS and Redis are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can go to previous command with `UP arrow` (unless you run `redis-cli` on a [non-TTY](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)), but there was a bug related to keeping history in `redis-cli` which could occur in two **rather rare** cases:

1. when history location was overridden via `REDISCLI_HISTFILE` environment variable being set to `/dev/null`, or
2. when `HOME` environment variable is not set for some reason.

It was fixed in version [4.0.7 of Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis/releases/tag/4.0.7) and in [4.0.2.1-alpha of Redis for Windows](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases/tag/v4.0.2.1-alpha).